# Upload pdf files from bot with Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I want to select a pdf file from the bot and send it through a Web Api but I have not obtained any documentation, if you could support me with this it would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a PDF, but you cannot send a local fie. It has to be uploaded somewhere or encoded. So, sending with activity and `contentUrl` of either `data:image/png;base64,${imageBase64}` or `https://www.example.com/path/to/file.pdf`

Please see more info explained in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/4815#issuecomment-729464613). Also be aware that different channels behave differently with attachments (See end of conversation in that same thread).

Edit: Actually, the change to be able to send a binary is currently in the works. Please watch [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/5118).