# How to add pdf in bot composer using File/Attachment prompt?

Tags: bots, botframework, bot-framework-composer

Hi I'm working on bot framework composer. Suppose a user need to upload a pdf to bot, how can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815768/upload-pdf-files-from-bot-with-bot-framework-composer) which covers this exact scenario. Additionally, you might find the [documentation for user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-ask-for-user-input?tabs=v2x) in Composer useful.